# Redux when to update state before or after async operation?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, redux

I am working on a paginated and sorted table. My initial pagination state is like this

```
pagination: {
  sort: 'id',
  order: 'asc',
  page: 1,
  limit: 10
}
```

when a user clicks on a page number or next/previous button I dispatch an action to change `page` and immediately after that I dispatch action to fetch the data from server. This works well but what should I do if a server error occur. I have two solutions in my mind

1) Rollback the pagination to previous state on error dispatching API_ERROR

2) Update pagination state only after success, so in my thunk after getting the response I dispatch updatePagination action.

My current handler on page click is something like this

```
onPageChange (page) {
  // Dispatch action to change page state
  this.props.changePage(page)

  // Dispatch action to fetch from server
  this.props.fetchSomePaginatedResponse()
}
```

Then the thunk `fetchSomePaginatedResponse` gets pagination object from state to build URI string.

I can also dispatch `changePage` action in thunk's success. Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I'd use is

```
class Pagination extends Component {
    ...
    onPageChange = ( event, page ) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.setCurrentPage( page );
    };
    render() {
        ...
        return pages.map( ( page, key ) => {
            return <a
                       key={ key }
                       href={ generatePageUrl( page ) }
                       onClick={ event => this.onPageChange( event, page ) }>
                       { page }
                   </a>
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}

export default connect(
    ( state ) => ( {
        currentPage: getCurrentPage( state ),
    } ),
    { setCurrentPage }
)( Pagination );
```

where `setCurrentPage` is a react redux thunk and dispatches two actions

```
setCurrentPage( dispatch, page ) {
    return ( dispatch ) => {
        dispatch( { type: API_PAGE_FETCH } ); // Maybe set isFetching: true in your state tree

        // asyncApiRequest should return a promise
        asyncApiRequest( `http://api.example.com/get-page?page=${ page }` )
            .then( data => dispatch( { type: API_PAGE_RECEIVE, data, page } ) )
            .catch( error => dispatch( { type: API_PAGE_ERROR, error } ) );
    }
}
```

This pattern works well because you only need to worry about changing the page in your component and nothing else like handling network errors etc